# Manipulating values of struct data type with a function

Tags: c++, function, struct

I'm learning about struct types in C++ and I tried to write a function that would change the values of the members of a struct type variable. 
However, it produces an unexpected output and I can't figure out why this is happening. 
    /*Program to test struct types*/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
struct myStruct
{
    string a;
    string b;
    int c;
    float d;
};

void assignValues(myStruct myobj)
{
    myobj.a = "foobar";
    myobj.b = "Foo Bar";
    myobj.c = 12;
    myobj.d = 15.223;
}
int main()
{
    myStruct x;
    cout << x.a <<endl;
    //x.a = "Hello world";
    //x.b = "This is C++";
    //x.c = 10;
    //x.d = 13.1332;
    assignValues(x);
    cout << x.a<<endl;
    cout << x.b << endl;
    cout << x.c << endl;
    cout << x.d << endl;
}
```

If I use the individual assignment statements, (that I have commented out in the code) instead of the assignValues() function, I get the expected output.

PS: The values I expected for the output are as follows:
foobar,
Foo Bar,
12,
15.223

Comment: Pass by reference! You are passing by value, which basically passes a copy of the structure object to the function and the function modifys the copy not the original object.Original object still has Indeterminate values, since the object was never initialized.

Comment: How do I 'pass by reference'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass myStruct argument by reference to assignValue function, so it can be modified:

```
void assignValues(myStruct& myobj)
                         ^^^ pass by reference
{
    myobj.a = "foobar";
    myobj.b = "Foo Bar";
    myobj.c = 12;
    myobj.d = 15.223;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. Together with the comment made by Als, this post told me what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can pass a pointer to function:

```
void assignValues(myStruct* myobj) //<---- pointer
{
    myobj->a = "foobar";
    myobj->b = "Foo Bar";
    myobj->c = 12;
    myobj->d = 15.223;
}
```

Comment: You can, but it’s generally not recommended. Among other things, pointers can be null. This cannot happen with references.

Comment: O really? Sure they can be null, bad, etc. It's just another way to modify data, isn't it? Or today nobody uses pointers?